# Запрос: Показать склады на которых отсутствует товар

Tags: sql

Имеем таблицы: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Покажем распределение товаров по складам:

select * from inventories
order by product_id;

Покажем ассортимент каждого склада:

select * from inventories
order by warehouse_id;

Вопрос: а как показать склады на которых нет товара?

Вот пример данных и нужного результата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

склады на которых отсутствует товар:

```
select 
    w.warehouse_id, 
    w.warehouse_name 
from warehouses w 
where 
    not exists (select 1 from products p inner join inventories i on p.product_id = i.product_id and i.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id)
order by w.warehouse_id
```

показывает все склады для товара в которых этот товар отсутствует:

```
SELECT 
    P.PRODUCT_ID,
    W.WAREHOUSE_ID
FROM PRODUCTS P CROSS JOIN WAREHOUSES W
MINUS
SELECT 
    P.PRODUCT_ID, 
    A.WAREHOUSE_ID
FROM PRODUCTS P CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT 
    I.PRODUCT_ID,
    W.WAREHOUSE_ID
    FROM INVENTORIES I INNER JOIN WAREHOUSES W ON I.WAREHOUSE_ID = W.WAREHOUSE_ID AND I.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
    ) A
```

Comment: смотрите мне нужно, что бы результат был таким: product_id  1, warehouse__id 2,7,9; product_id  2, warehouse__id 5,6,8 и тд. Ваш код возвращает пустую таблицу; Спасибо!

Comment: т.е показываем склады на которых нет данного товара

Comment: какого конкретно нет товара, у вас есть его идентификатор? или вы просто хотите получить список идентификаторов складов по каждому товару через запятую? и напишите какая у вас база данных в вопросе.

Comment: какого товара не важно, любого. лучше всех товаров. Да нет не через запятую, это я просто так написал, тк формат комментария не позволяет таблицу нарисовать. Нужна таблица: первый столбец Product_id, второй столбец warehouse_id. таблица показывает все склады для товара в которых этот товар отсутствует. База oracle. Спасибо!

Comment: второй вариант возвращает тоже пустую таблицу

Comment: добавьте в ваш начальный вопрос всё необходимую информацию по данным таблиц в виде скрипта и желаемый результат в виде примера данных. и исправьте ваш исходный вопрос.

Comment: добавлю данные в виде тестового примера, тк не знаю как добавить данные в виде скрипта

Comment: добавил картинку с тестовыми данными

Comment: немного исправил картинку

Comment: исправил запрос

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 101 Column: 1, на строке где команда except

Comment: у вас Oracle , нужен MINUS

Comment: да все правильно. Спасибо! Но если честно для меня такой код пока не понятен. Если можно, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хорошие курсы или книги.

Comment: можете начать отсюда https://oracleplsql.ru/contents-oracle-plsql.html  если ответ был вам полезен, то поставьте галочку

Comment: Спасибо! да поставил. Спасибо за терпение!